# How to find the mouse move speed in windows form?

Tags: c#, mouseevent, windows-forms-designer, onmousemove

How can i able to found the mouse moving speed in windows form control in mouse events. Based on the mouse moving speed I need to move the control. Like the mouse move with left mouse button, based on the mouse speed I need to move my control?

Comment: You can't make this work reliably  It just isn't necessary, you don't care about speed at all when you simply reposition by the new mouse position.  If you did not get a new update for a while, for whatever reason, then it still works correctly.

Comment: For a simple move: Do not use mouse speed. Use position.

Comment: I have implemented the touch Panning operation by using mouse events like MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp. The Panning operation working perfectly as per your suggestion, I have using the mouse position. But also I need to implement the swipe scrolling support in same mouse events how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:
starts a timer when the mouse is moved for the first time and save the starting position.
If it continue moving, look if the move is in a straight line, if it's not, stop the timer and then apply a formula to calculate the total distance traveled and divide it by the time it took.
If there are more than one "straight line", you can use an average (sum/cant).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code example from Microsoft can help you:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SystemInfoBrowser
{
    public partial class SystemInfoBrowserForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;

    public SystemInfoBrowserForm()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        InitForm();

        // Add each property of the SystemInformation class to the list box.
        Type t = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation);
        PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();
        for (int i = 0; i < pi.Length; i++)
            listBox1.Items.Add(pi[i].Name);
        textBox1.Text = "The SystemInformation class has " + pi.Length.ToString() + " properties.\r\n";

        // Configure the list item selected handler for the list box to invoke a 
        // method that displays the value of each property.
        listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Return if no list item is selected.
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1) return;
        // Get the property name from the list item.
        string propname = listBox1.Text;

        if (propname == "PowerStatus")
        {
            // Cycle and display the values of each property of the PowerStatus property.
            textBox1.Text += "\r\nThe value of the PowerStatus property is:";
            Type t = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.PowerStatus);
            PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();
            for (int i = 0; i < pi.Length; i++)
            {
                object propval = pi[i].GetValue(SystemInformation.PowerStatus, null);
                textBox1.Text += "\r\n    PowerStatus." + pi[i].Name + " is: " + propval.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Display the value of the selected property of the SystemInformation type.
            Type t = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation);
            PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();
            PropertyInfo prop = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < pi.Length; i++)
                if (pi[i].Name == propname)
                {
                    prop = pi[i];
                    break;
                }
            object propval = prop.GetValue(null, null);
            textBox1.Text += "\r\nThe value of the " + propname + " property is: " + propval.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void InitForm()
    {
        // Initialize the form settings
        this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.listBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 16);
        this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(172, 496);
        this.listBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.textBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(188, 16);
        this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
        this.textBox1.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical;
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(420, 496);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(616, 525);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
        this.Text = "Select a SystemInformation property to get the value of";
    }
}
```

}

It is from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.mousespeed(v=vs.110).aspx) and uses the SystemInformation class to show you some properties, it also shows you the MouseSpeed, which reaches from 1 - 20 and should be set to 10 by default. You just have to extract the code parts for just this property and you should be set.

[image]

Comment: I need the mouse moving speed in OnMouseMove override method, in that how can i found that?